# webBrowser control adding custom referer in c#

Tags: c#, user-agent, referer

Hello I would like to ask how to add to this code line custom referer information, becouse I tried add after user-agent but dont worked thanks.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://yoursite.com", "_self", null, "User-Agent: Custom User Agent string");
```

Answer (score 7):

Put in a line break:

```
"User-Agent: Custom User Agent string\r\nReferer: Custom Referrer"
```

Comment: thanks its working, and one more question if I want get these strings from text boxes like "User-Agent: textBox1.Text\r\nReferer: textBox2.Text" how I should write correctly?

Comment: This sounds like a separate question, would you mind posting it as a new question?